# How to generate repeating numbers in sequence

Tags: sql, oracle, with-statement, rownum

I would like to generate this sequence

```
col sequence 
  01 01
  01 02
  01 03 
  01 04
  01 05
  02 01
  02 02
  02 03
  02 04
  02 05
  ..
  ..
  12 01
  12 02
  12 03
  12 04
  12 04
```

And add this as a sequence to another select.

Comment: you say "add this to a select". Are you sure generating a dummy table with a sequence is the best solution ? You can use the analitical function row_number to achieve this as well - no need to join to another table at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hierarchical query might help to produce result you posted:

```
SQL> with
  2  c1 as
  3    (select lpad(1 + level - 1, 2, '0') col1
  4     from dual
  5     connect by level <= 12
  6    ),
  7  c2 as
  8    (select lpad(1 + level - 1, 2, '0') col2
  9     from dual
 10     connect by level <= 5
 11    )
 12  select c1.col1, c2.col2
 13  from c1 cross join c2
 14  order by c1.col1, c2.col2;

CO CO
-- --
01 01
01 02
01 03
01 04
01 05
02 01
02 02
02 03
02 04
02 05
03 01
03 02
<snip>
11 04
11 05
12 01
12 02
12 03
12 04
12 05

60 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Why create two lists of numbers?  One is sufficient.

Comment: Because the first column goes from 01 - 12, while the second goes from 01 - 05 for each first column value, @Gordon?

Comment: @Littlefoot . . . A `where` clause would handle that.

Answer (score 0):

You want `row_numner()` :

```
select col, row_number() over (partition by col order by col) as sequence
from table t;
```

You can use sub-query for further operation.